# Are correlated univariate normals equivalent to a bivariate normal?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

If I know that $A \sim \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2_A)$ and $B \sim \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2_B)$ and that $A$ and $B$ have a correlation coefficient of $\rho$, does this mean that it *must* be that case that

$\begin{bmatrix} A \\ B \end{bmatrix} \sim  \mathcal N\left( \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} \sigma^2_A & \rho \sigma_A \sigma_B \\ \rho \sigma_A \sigma_B & \sigma_B^2    \end{bmatrix} \right) \>?$

Or is that just one possibility?

And what about for other distributions?

Comment: **Related**: [Is it possible to have a pair of Gaussian random variables for which the joint distribution is not Gaussian?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/30159/2970)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just one possibility. Wikipedia suggests a [counter example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Two_normally_distributed_random_variables_need_not_be_jointly_bivariate_normal), in which two dependent normal random variables are not bivariate normal.

If $A$ and $B$ are independent, then the vector $(A,B)$ *is* bivariate normal.